# Unescape escaped value for regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, escaping

I have an escaped value like this:

```
var _re_escape_regex = new RegExp( '(\\' + [ '/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '$', '^', '-' ].join('|\\') + ')', 'g' ); 
val.replace( _re_escape_regex, '\\$1' );
```

How can I unescape `val` in JavaScript/jQuery, that is, escape a string such that it can be used in a regular expression?

To further clarify, I'm using the datatables.js plugin ([plugin code](https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.js)). This plugin has this function:

```
/**
     * Escape a string such that it can be used in a regular expression
     *
     *  @param {string} val string to escape
     *  @returns {string} escaped string
     */
    escapeRegex: function ( val ) {
        return val.replace( _re_escape_regex, '\\$1' );
    }
```

Definition of `_re_escpae_regex` is:

```
var _re_escape_regex = new RegExp( '(\\' + [ '/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\', '$', '^', '-' ].join('|\\') + ')', 'g' );
```

In my code I'm doing:

```
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(some_unescaped_value);
```

Now I need to invert what is done by the above escapeRegex function with `some_unescaped_value`, because I need `val` without escapes made by this function.

Comment: Of course. For example: source string value is "aaaa-bbbb", output is "aaaa\-bbbb". Need to get back to source value by inverting what was done to source value.

Comment: For Escape: `return string.replace(regex, function ($0) {
    return '\\' + $0;
});` To UnEscape: `return string.replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1');`. Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ahndru7u/)